# inserting an item to a @Html.DropdownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my current razor code for a simple select.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Season", Model.Seasons.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.Name, Value = s.SeasonId.ToString() }), new { @class = "sel_season" })
```

What I want to do is add/insert an additional option item called "All".
I have tried Concat, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Season", Model.Seasons.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.Name, Value = s.SeasonId.ToString() }).Concat( new {"All", "0"}), new { @class = "sel_season" })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sample uses an overloaded extension method in the [HtmlHelper class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504967%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
@Html.DropDownList("Season"
    , Model.Seasons.Select(s => new SelectListItem {
        Text = s.Name,
        Value = s.SeasonId.ToString()
    })
    , "All"
    , new { @class = "sel_season" }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
@Html.DropDownList("Season", 
                  Model.Seasons
                    .Select(s =>
                       new SelectListItem { Text = s.Name, Value = s.SeasonId.ToString() })
                    .ToList().Insert(0, SelectListItem { Text = "All",Value =  "0"}), 
                   new { @class = "sel_season" })
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as what I was trying to do with Concat. My problem is I couldn't figure out how to create a SelectListItem.